# Traefik v2 TLSStore not used and no error messages in the logs

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, traefik, traefik-ingress

### Environment

- Traefik-Version: `2.10.5`
- Kuberntes-Version: `1.27.4`

### Given configurations

1. Secret: `ingress-controller-traefik-cluster-cert`

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Secret
   metadata:
     name: ingress-controller-traefik-cluster-cert
     namespace: kube-system
   type: kubernetes.io/tls
   data:
     tls.crt: LS0t # ... snip
     tls.key: LS0t # ... snip
   ```
2. TLSStore `ingress-controller-traefik-default`

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
   kind: TLSStore
   metadata:
     name: ingress-controller-traefik-default
     namespace: kube-system
   spec:
     defaultCertificate:
       secretName: ingress-controller-traefik-cluster-cert
     certificates:
       - secretName: ingress-controller-traefik-cluster-cert
   ```
3. IngressRoute `my-app-https`

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
   kind: IngressRoute
   metadata:
     name: my-app-https
     certificates:
       - secretName: ingress-controller-traefik-cluster-cert
   ```
4. IngressRoute `my-app-https`

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
   kind: IngressRoute
   metadata:
     name: my-app-https
     namespace: my-namespace
     namespace: kube-system
   spec:
     entryPoints:
       - https
     routes:
       - kind: Rule
         match: Host(`my-domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/my-app`)
         services:
           - name: my-app
             port: 80
     tls:
       store:
         name: ingress-controller-traefik-default
   ```

### Test scenario

1. Insecure

   - Command:

     ```bash
     curl --insecure https://my-domain.com/my-app
     ```
   - Actual result:

     ```
     {"status":200,"ok":true}
     ```
2. Regular

   - Command:

     ```bash
     curl https://my-domain.com/my-app
     ```
   - Actual result:

     ```
     curl: (60) schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - [..]
     More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

     curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
     establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
     how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
     ```
   - Issuer: `TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT`

### My question

The target certificate is not picked-up from the secret `ingress-controller-traefik-cluster-cert` and I do not see any meaningful message in the logs of traefik. Also not log level `debug` gives me a hint so far. I only see:

```
time="2023-11-19T21:56:25Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, fallback to the internal generated certificate" tlsStoreName=kube-system-ingress-controller-traefik-default
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks already in advance.
spec:
entryPoints:
- https
routes:
- kind: Rule
match: Host(`my-domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/my-app`)
services:
- name: my-app
port: 80
tls:
store:
name: ingress-controller-traefik-default
```

### Test scenario

1. Insecure

   - Command:

     ```bash
     curl --insecure https://my-domain.com/my-app
     ```
   - Actual result:

     ```
     {"status":200,"ok":true}
     ```
2. Regular

   - Command:

     ```bash
     curl https://my-domain.com/my-app
     ```
   - Actual result:

     ```
     curl: (60) schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - [..]
     More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

     curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
     establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
     how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
     ```
   - Issuer: `TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT`

### My question

The target certificate is not picked-up from the secret `ingress-controller-traefik-cluster-cert` and I do not see any meaningful message in the logs of traefik. Also not log level `debug` gives me a hint so far. I only see:

```
time="2023-11-19T21:56:25Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, fallback to the internal generated certificate" tlsStoreName=kube-system-ingress-controller-traefik-default
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks already in advance.